# Argument of a complex number (Cops)

Tags: code-golf, math, cops-and-robbers, calculus

*This is the cop's thread, where one should post the scrambled code. Here is the [**robbers' thread**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271854/argument-of-a-complex-number-robbers) where the cracked source should be posted and linked to the cop's answer.*

---

Task: Write the shortest *safe* program that given two inputs \$x,y\$, outputs \$\arg(x+iy)\$, where \$\arg(z)\$ is defined as the angle between the positive real axis and the line joining the origin and \$z\$.

---

This is [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers), so the rules are:

- In your answer, post a scrambled version of your source code, which should not work. (should be written in any order)
- You can take input/output in any standard way.
- Hardcoding is forbidden.
- Standard loopholes are banned.
- If your code is cracked by the robbers, you must mention that it has been cracked in your title and include a spoiler containing your exact code.
- Same thing applies for safe answers. (mention in the title that it's safe and include the spoiler)
- You must specify the programming language you used and byte count.
- Answers are considered safe after 5 days.

---

- You can assume that \$|x|,|y|\le5\$.
- You can also assume that \$x,y\in\mathbb Z\$
- Minimum decimal precision is 5 decimal places with any rounding mechanism of your choice.
- **You must state the rounding mechanism in your answer.**
- You are not allowed to return as fractions (numerator/denominators)

---

```
+-------------+
|Example cases|
+-------------+

+ - + - + -------------------------- +
| x | y | Output (10 decimal places) |
+ - + - + -------------------------- +
| 5 | 5 |        0.7853981633        |
+ - + - + -------------------------- +
| 1 | 4 |        1.3258176636        |
+ - + - + -------------------------- +
| 0 | 2 |        1.5707963267        |
+ - + - + -------------------------- +
| 0 | 0 |         Undefined          |
+ - + - + -------------------------- +
| -1| 0 |        3.1415926535        |
+ - + - + -------------------------- +
| 1 | 0 |              0             |
+ - + - + -------------------------- +
| -2| 1 |        2.6779450445        |
+ - + - + -------------------------- +
| -3| -4|       -2.2142973355        |
+ - + - + -------------------------- +
| 2 | -5|       -1.1902899496        |
+ - + - + -------------------------- +
```

The shortest safe answer by April 15 will be considered the winner.

Comment: (1,0) has argument 0 and (-1,0) has argument pi. You should also have test cases in quadrants II, III, and IV.

Comment: @Tbw I’ll update the question

Comment: i dont get it; what are the robbers supposed to do?

Comment: @Seggan Did I not explain it well enough on [the robbers’ thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271854/argument-of-a-complex-number-robbers)? sorry if I didn’t.

Comment: Is there a reason for this task along with this kind of cops and robbers? Seems kind-of random.

Comment: @xnor why would you say that?

Comment: Does the output have to be in radians, or can it be in degrees?

Comment: @mbomb007 Radians would most definitely be preferred.

Comment: I would also like to note that this challenge is basically just asking people to implement the [`atan2` function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: Does it matter what happens when the input is `0,0`?

Comment: @GregMartin (0,0) should be undefined because there is no calculable angle between it and the origin. (Or, simply put, it should be undefined because \$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\tan^{-1}(y/x)=DNE\$)

Comment: I understand that the mathematical function is undefined; I'm asking whether it matters what the code returns in that case, as long as it doesn't return a number.

Comment: Do we have to specify the input format (for example, two numbers, a string, an array), or is that part of what the robbers have to guess?

Comment: @GregMartin If it doesn’t return a number, then it should probably return undefined or however the programming language handles indeterminacy

Comment: @LuisMendo No, that is something the robbers have to guess (as long as the source code is scrambled)

Comment: The example for `-3,-4` result should be `-2.21429743558`?

Comment: @Julian [Yes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=arg%5C%2840%29-3-4i%5C%2841%29)

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua 0.10.0](https://www.uiua.org/), 14 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271870/91267)

```
↥⍥⌵)∠.⊃±×(0∩¬÷
```

Does not round the answer at all beyond what Uiua does natively.

Edit: my solution as a bit different from the cracked answer:

> `⍥(×÷.0)¬±↥⊃∩⌵∠`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271870/91267)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271862/76323)

```javascript
""%%%%%%%%%%()+0134445566677788[]``aaaacdeeeelnpsuv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/R@cn1NakpmfZ/tfSUkVDjQ0tQ0MjU1MTExNzczMzM3NLSyiYxMSEoEgOSUVCHLyCopLy/5bcyXn5xXn56Tq5eSna8DM0jDVMdXUVNDXVzDQM7cwNba0MDQzNv4PAA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271862).

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes, [cracked by @totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271871)

```
*crane*@RANT@
```

Displays the result to 6 significant figures, hence at least 5 decimal places.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271871).

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 53 bytes, [cracked by @att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271990)

```
B{[[@#&#&#&#=!=/+<+/1122900,eternal,emote,ego]]}.IIII
```

Hint/teaser: the 31-byte subset `@##&+{[}].,,,/112aeeeegIIImnrtt` is almost a solution to this challenge, but it erroneously returns an error for inputs \$(x,0)\$ when \$x<0\$.

Solution to the teaser:

> `Im@Integrate[1/e,{e,1.,#+#2I}]&`

> \$\mathop{\rm arg}(x+iy)\$ is the imaginary part of \$\log(x+iy)\$; and \$\log z\$ is the antiderivative of \$\frac1z\$ (just like in the real numbers). When \$z\$ is complex but not real, Mathematica understands that it should do a contour integral that correctly computes \$\log z\$. However, when \$z\$ is real, Mathematica interprets this as a regular integral in the real numbers, and complains (understandably) when \$z\$ is negative.

Actual solution:

> `Im@Integrate[1/e,{e,1.,#+#2I+Boole[#<0&&#2==0]/9!I}]&`

> So we spend 22 more bytes adding a tiny imaginary part to any negative real input, forcing Mathematica to do the complex contour integral without affecting the output very much.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271990)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 55 bytes, safe

The output is not explicitly rounded.

```javascript
(())*++++++,,,,-/6=====BBBBBBBMMM[[[]]]aeffhhhhhrrrrrtu
```

#### Hint 1

> This computes `Math[Buffer(97, 116, 97, 110) + 2]`, starting with `B = 6` and `r = 1`.

#### Hint 2

> We compute `h = "1"+6 = 16`, `97 = 16*6+1`, `116 = "1"+16` and `110 = 116-6`.

#### Solution

> ```javascript
> Math[Buffer([M=(B=6,h=[r=B/B]+B)*B+r,h=r+++h,M,h-B])+r]
> ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc6xDsIgFEDR3a9gBHloqa0by9v5AsJAKoimKYZWfx@Zpa4nd7hP93HrlB@vTSzp5ktQRbstGnyH4DM1WlFUV4jKZIVntBzZEXmukDnnETREgZbxbMuUljXN/jSnOw2UjEBGxg4/OgCRrfZAula7PyrkbrujEkTfqBhAXFqtv7UtXw)

Comment: For anyone else trying to solve this confused by the lack of I/O: I'm fairly certain this is of the form `Math[xxx]` where `xxx` evaluates to `atan2` somehow.

Comment: This has been safe for a while, can you reveal the solution?

Comment: @emanresuA Done!

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 46 bytes, [cracked by vindobona](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272051)

```
####&,22ACLNPT[[[[[[]]]]]]aabdeiilnoooorrssstt
```

Sorry I don't have words like Greg Martin did. Expects `[x,y]`.

Comment: `sort[boatloads[ironies]]` ;)

Comment: Just to check (I'm sure you're right): there really should be four `#`s? If there were three `#`s, I've cracked it.

Comment: @GregMartin yes, four

Comment: I can't figure out the last `#`  :p  What's the convention here: should I post my near miss to help other robbers, or just let the cop post stand for itself?

Comment: @GregMartin I'd be interested in seeing what you have, at least

Comment: I've got `N[ToPolarCoordinates[List[#,##2]][[Abs[2]]]]&`. Using `##2` instead of `#2` used up one of the two "extra" `#`s, but I'm missing what to do with the other extra one.

Comment: @GregMartin if it helps, you're very close

Comment: @GregMartin @att Would this one `N[ToPolarCoordinates[List[##, ##]][[Abs[2] 2]]] &`  fix the issue with the extra `#` ?

Comment: @vindobona I believe you've got it! You clearly understand hyperspherical coordinates in 4d space better than I do  :D  Please do the honors on the robbers' thread.

Comment: @GregMartin I actually struggled a while until I got to try it in 4d :D. I just posted it, all credit goes to you and to `@att` of course.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 46 bytes, safe

```
@@####^^&&--+{[[(())]]}.,,//122255AIISbmmmmmsu
```

As with my other submissions, this is an unnamed function of two variables. The output is printed to the default number of decimal places, and is correct to at least 11 decimal places. Solution:

> `Im@Sum[-5(1-(#/Abs@#)^.2)^m/m,{m,52}]&[#+I#2]&`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYu9CsIwFEZ3n@JCoLR4r22iGYU4dhMcQwpRLO1wHTROIc8e01Kn8/1w2IfpyT7MD5/Hc@7Z3L5sSdeSatFe7h8jmuGgmoFbxsioVXKVFfteKFfl63t@BTuCMQbiDiBqBJ0QokQ4LewQ1MZuIckt/EkKoYgg13JEoNUrK@lUjuTyDw) Explanation:

> At its heart this code is simply one of the standard ways of calculating the argument of the complex number \$x+iy\$ as the imaginary part of its logarithm: `Im@Log[#+I#2]&` or, more verbosely, `Im@Log@#&[#+I#2]&`. The new approach is to replace \$\log (1-w)\$ by its power series \$-\sum_{m=1}^\infty w^m/m\$. Applying this formula with \$w=1-(x+iy)\$ gives

> `Im@Sum[-(1-#)^m/m,{m,52}]&[#+I#2]&`

> (The `52` ensures we're summing enough terms of the power series to get the required accuracy; the number itself is pretty arbitrary.) Unfortunately, the power series only converges when \$w\$ is close to \$1\$. So we exploit two mathematical tricks: first, we use the fact that \$\log z = 5\log(z^{1/5})\$ (this is dangerous in the complex numbers generally, but it's safe if we're declaring ahead of time that \$-\pi<\arg z\le\pi\$ as this challenge does) to limit the argument of \$w\$ in this application:

> `Im@Sum[-5(1-#^.2)^m/m,{m,52}]&[#+I#2]&`

> Second, we limit the modulus of \$w\$ by just replacing the input divided by its own modulus, resulting in the final code:

> `Im@Sum[-5(1-(#/Abs@#)^.2)^m/m,{m,52}]&[#+I#2]&`

> After these two tricks, the only numbers we input into the power series are those along a circular arc through the origin, which is well inside the radius of convergence of the power series and thus allows its truncation to 52 terms to be a good enough approximation to the true value.

> [image: graph of inputs to final function]

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 50 bytes, safe

```
##&(())**+,,.////0012@@DHIMN[[[[[]]]]]^^adeinrsttu
```

Expects `[x,y]`.

Hint:

> The result could be exact, if not for `N`

> `Minus`

### Solution

> `Head[((1.+#*#)^I^2&//Minus/@D[r@t,t][[0,0]])[]]/*N`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcW7CsIwFADQvb8RKG29MQ/bUcngoIMiOIZbCH1ghmaocQrpr0dqPcuZjH8Nk/G2M2k8pstgel0UYr8jFSnbaytzxm7Wfd5MnfWsPHjUmgNHLDUiq@7pMVvnNaGnUSmC@fLsjFtCFhpoImRBQL3GQW7xNSq2/1EJ4vcBaB2zmL4)

> This is mostly just a convoluted way to fetch [`ArcTan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html) by performing a symbolic antiderivative.

> `Derivative[-1]` performs an antiderivative.

> `Derivative` is too obvious if all letters are present, but we can generate it with `D[r@t,t]`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d8lusihRKck9n/sfwA) `r` and `t` are red herrings.

> This yields `Derivative[1][r][t]`. We can fetch `Derivative[1]` by taking part `[[0,0]]`, and negate the `1` with `Minus/@`.

> Apply this on \$\arctan'\$ = `(1.+#*#)^I^2&` to obtain `ArcTan[#1]&`.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d8ltSizDChSlhqtaxgbrWGoraylrBmna6gW@z/2PwA)

> There are a number of ways to extract `ArcTan` from this expression, but this uses `Head[(...)[]]`. The last step is composition with `N`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 65 bytes, [cracked by @Guido](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272008/120105)

No rounding.

```c
hey, sexy
     #(()),,.2;<>aaaaaacdfffhhillllmnnnooorrsttttttuu{}
```

Comment: [Cracked by @Guido](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272008/120105)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 11 bytes, [cracked by @LdBeth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272224/101535)

```
*&_,.1:_.&^
```

Takes a complex number in the form of `x + 1j * y`. Output is not rounded. The behavior is identical to the built-in `12&o.`; returns zero on zero input.

### Hint 1

> A page that is two links away from [NuVoc](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/NuVoc) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes. Safe

```
*LUYYZjlssty
```

Non-required information provided as a courtesy for the robbers:

- Input is a row vector of two numbers.
- Output is not rounded.
- Input `[0 0]` gives output `0`.

### Solution

#### Code

> `tZysUL*sYlYj`
>
> Try at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=tZysUL%2asYlYj&inputs=%5B1+4%5D&version=22.8.0)!

#### Explanation

> `t   % Implicit input: row vector of two numbers. Duplicate`
>
> `Zy  % Size: gives [1 2]`
>
> `s   % Sum: gives 3`
>
> `U   % Square: gives 9`
>
> `L   % Paste from the 9th level of clipboard L: gives predefined literal [1 1i]`
>
> `*   % Multiply by original copy of input, element-wise`
>
> `s   % Sum: gives the complex number represented by the input`
>
> `Yl  % Logarithm`
>
> `Yj  % Imaginary part. Implicit display`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 22 bytes

```
ᵇİ0daṫȦ#+>Q[\\ik|¬¿÷∆∨
```

Input is taken as `[y,x]`, output is not rounded. The program quits when received `[0,0]`.
I had fun scrambling the code :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 47 bytes

```
0000000000000023344466778\\\\\\\aaaaadeuuuuuuu
```

Takes arguments in the order `y, x` and doesn't round. Original answer was invalid so you have five days to crack this starting from the time of this edit.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 68 bytes

No rounding; this one's a bit more complex, so I'm giving you all a hint ;)

```c
#include <math.h>
     (())*+,Iaaaaacceefffgllllnnnooooprrrtttttux{}
```

Comment: [Possible crack by @Guido](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272017/120105)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 50 bytes, [Cracked by @Mukundan314](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272016/91267)

```python
from math import*
def j(l,a):a*me.fog.magic(l+0b1)
```

No rounding.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272016/91267)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 69 bytes, [cracked by @Mukundan314](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271854/argument-of-a-complex-number-robbers/272034#272034)

```go
   ""(())./12468;PPaaaccceeefffhhilllmmmmnnnnooooppprrrsssttttuuwxx{}
```

#### Solution

> `import."math/cmplx";func Powfss(n complex128)float64{return Phase(n)}`

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjddM3ML8otK9JRyE0sy9JNzC3IqlKzTSvOSFQLyy9OKizXyFJLzgaKpFYZGFpppOfmJJWYm1UWpJaVFeQoBGYnFqRp5mrUQw9aD9YEM19BUqOaCii5YAKEB)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272034/91267)?

Comment: @Mukundan314 it seems to work on my end, so yes, I think it is a crack.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 57 bytes, [Cracked by @att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271939/120105)

```
()***++,,-/6:=AFIIILNNR[[[[[[]]]]]]__bbeefgmmoorrsuxxxyyy
```

Unsure if it is generally accepted to answer your own challenges or not, I just wanted to attempt it for fun.

Rounds to 6 sig figs (5 decimal places), like Greg Martin's 13-byte solution.

Intended solution:

> `f[x_,y_]:=NumberForm[Re[N[-I*Log[(x+I*y)/Abs[x+I*y]]]],6]`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271939)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes, [cracked by Greg Martin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271995/56178)

```
*+,6FIILNN[[[[]]]]begmmmoorruxy
```

<strike>Hopefully lasts more than 5 hours this time, also uses a different method.</strike> Lasted 10 hours! still cracked though :9

Intended sol:

> NumberForm[N[Im[Log[x+I*y]]],6]

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271995/56178)