# Argument of a complex number (Robbers)

Tags: code-golf, math, cops-and-robbers, calculus

<sub>V1.1: Added criterion to help with tiebreakers, a bit overkill but still.</sub>

---

**Task:** Crack the scrambled code for calculating the argument of a complex number \$z=x+iy\$ given two inputs.

You must post a comment in the [**cops’ thread**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271853/argument-of-a-complex-number-cops) with a link to your working source, mentioning clearly that you have **cracked it.** In your answer’s title, you must include a link to the original answer.

#### Rules:

- You may only change the order of the characters in the original source.
- Safe answers cannot be cracked anymore.
- See the other rules mentioned in the cops’ thread
- ***Please edit the answer you cracked***

---

Scoring Criterion:

- The person who has the most cracked answers wins.
- If there is a tie, then the total number of bytes cracked over all of the answers is taken into consideration, with the higher total byte count winning.
- If there is still a tie somehow, then the person who posted the answers over a shorter time period wins.

---

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes, cracks [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271860)

```javascript
eval(unescape`%4d%61%74%68["a%74a%6e"+7%5%5%8%30]`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczLCoMwEEDRfb9ChIGE1hcxDyn9ii5LwSEORQkZadTfT92Uuzmru@CByX/ndasiT5SfHPZt5vjIdGAQe6TkcaUR@glMB7YH414lnkAwVF4t6DMHqn2PMt8vnmPiQHXgj/i/hL5pKYumKdraOq0G1xml8g8)

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes, cracks [Greg Martin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271869)

```
Re@*N@*ArcTan
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@z8o1UHLz0HLsSg5JDHvf0lqcUmxgq1CdbWpjoJprY5CtaGOggmINtBRMILSBiBa1xDKgNG6RjoKhmCGsY6CLlgPUETXtLaWiyugKDOvREHfQUEjTcHBwUEBbI3mfwA)

Prints more than six significant figures on TIO, possibly because of the `Print` function or just... I dunno. :P

Comment: Well done! Yeah, the number of digits displayed is different in the application's environment than in a console version.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 48 bytes, cracks [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271889/91560)

```
N[ToPolarCoordinates[List[##,##]][[Abs[2]2]]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcmxCsIwEADQPb8R6HSBJrajUnEVKegWbjhri4E2gSRbSH89Wuv0hrdQfI8LRTNQKdPxph@udzP5i3P@ZSzFMeirCVFzDpwjan1@Bq1QIWJVem/st8Rp6jqO1XofyK6JpRbaDCxJaDZqUDv1hpC7f4QC@fMAoskslw8)

All credit goes to [Greg Martin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56178/greg-martin) for actually finding the initial solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua 0.10.0](https://www.uiua.org/), 14 bytes, cracks [@Tbw](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271856/91267)

```
⍥¬0(÷×.±↥⊃∩⌵∠)
```

[Try on Uiua Pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4o2lwqwwKMO3w5cuwrHihqXiioPiiKnijLXiiKApCkYgNSA1CkYgNCAxCkYgMiAwCkYgMCAwCkYgMCDCrzEKRiAwIDEKRiAxIMKvMgpGIMKvNCDCrzMKRiDCrzUgMgo=)

Comment: This answer does not produce the same outputs as my code. If it helps, my code more closely matches the example cases (one of them in particular).

Comment: @Tbw, Should be fixed now

Comment: This does match my answer's outputs, but is still somewhat different in structure. I don't know the rules for this, but if it is cracked, I will include my code as a spoiler in my answer.

Comment: @Tbw, at this point it is consider cracked; feel free to include your code as a spoiler in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 57 bytes, cracks [CrSb0001](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271926)

```
f[x_,y_]:=N[Arg[x+y*I]+(b-b)/6*FIILNR[e,e][][]*mmoorsuxy]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8tuiJepzI@1srWL9qxKD26QrtSyzNWWyNJN0lT30zLzdPTxy8oOlUnNTYaCLVyc/Pzi4pLKypj/wcUZeaVRCvr2qU5OCjHqtUFJyfm1VVzVZvqmNbqcFUb6piAKAMdIwhlAKJ0DSE0lNI10jEE08Y6uia1XLX/AQ)

Be careful what you allow :)

Comment: To be fair, that was not what was intended lol. I'll edit my ans. with my intended sol.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 53 bytes, cracks [Greg Martin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271877)

```
Im@Integrate[1/e,{e,1.,#+#2I+Boole[#<0&&#2==0]/9!I}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcUxCsMgFADQ3VsUwSXfRm0yFGqRbm6FjuIgwTSBaiC4ibm6JU3f8oJLkw8uzYOro6w6KB2Tf68uecNbD9kDPwNusNDNY1k@3uAbIwQLKZltryddLKnPdY7JYHoflcKWbK/BxS2j3ENfAGUO3R4DccT2KD/@RwXw3xegXUGlfgE)

I couldn't figure out what the 9 was doing there until I reread the question...

Comment: Great job! I thought about making it a bit more obscure by changing `Integrate[1/e,{e,1.,...` to `Integrate[1/Null,{,1.,...`. But I figured if someone figures out the `Integrate` paradigm they should get the win :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 50 bytes, cracks [@CursorCoercer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271966/91267)

```python
lambda e,f:log(e+(1.0j*f)).imag
from cmath import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY5BDoIwFET3nGISNi22hFZJiIlLb-GmKgUMpU1TF17EjRs2eCdvIxE1Xf28P3_mz-PpbqG1wzhp7HCYrkHz6iV7ZY5nhZrpbW8bUq-IyItLpinNO6OaRHtrcDIqtOiMsz5kX-fd-W4IRJOSoaQ0-aFg2ERYMMgZU0SLglIgxd576_-HXHyEOCdGLhlEzGsGHj-adT73WNqN4zLf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes, cracks [CrSb0001](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271940/56178)

```
NumberForm[Im[Log[N[x+I*y]]],6]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78nxZdEa9TGR9rZfvfrzQ3KbXILb8oN9ozN9onPz3aL7pC21OrMjY2Vscs9n9AUWZeSXSagoODg0K1QrWpjoJprY5CtaGOggmINtBRMILSBiBa1xDKgNG6RjoKhmCGsY6CLlgPUETXtFahNvY/AA) (I don't know why but TIO doesn't reduce `NumberForm[...,6]` like Mathematica does)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 65 bytes, cracks [Blue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271918/122407)

```c
#include <math.h>,x
float h(float y, float s){return atan2(y,s);}
```

the elevation of ,x was quite a surprise

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 68 bytes, cracks? [Blue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271920/122407)

```c
#include <complex.h>
float h(float n, float at){return carg(n+at*I);}
```

-- Am I right to believe that for imaginary reasons, a space character transformed into a semi-colon?

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 69 bytes, cracks [@bigyihsuan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272018/91267)

```go
import."math/cmplx";func Posswf(n complex128)float64{return Phase(n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc9BCoMwEAXQdT3FkFVCiTVWS8FLeIUQjEpNIjFSQTx7amqXVZczj/@ZqY3vuXjxugLFWx1FreqNdYCkcshvQ4wUd81NqL6bUCFHLaA0w/CWWIMw67aaWPoksjPcPbLZVm60GsqGDxXWZPHfRGjHBObosjbHpW216zT@9UAOV4C8JaT47yx4tu9J8PTEk12n7NjhxGkanO37fXV6cH/I0@3/xX8A)