# Can I Clear The Grid?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, grid

I recently found [this game](https://en.gamesaien.com/game/color_tiles/) and have been enjoying it. Basically, there is a grid of colored tiles and you act by clicking on empty spaces. When you click an empty space, the first tile (if any) in each of the four axis-aligned directions is selected. If any color appears more than once, all tiles of that color are destroyed (and if it hits two of one color and two of another, all four are destroyed).

See the following example:

```
. . R . .      . . . . .      . . . . .
R---x G .      . . . G .      . . . . .
. . | . .  =>  . . . | .  =>  . . . . .
. G | . R      . G---x R      . . . . R
. . R . .      . . . . .      . . . . .
```

The game is played on a time limit and clicking a space that does nothing will incur a time penalty, but for this challenge, I am just interested in one thing: can I clear the entire grid?

For example, in this grid, two clicks are enough to clear the grid:

```
. R . .
. B . B
. R . .
```

Clicking between the `B`s opens a space between the `R`s that can be clicked to finish it.

On the other hand, in this grid, there is no way to eliminate all tiles:

```
G . G . G
```

If you click between the right two `G`s, then you can't eliminate the left one, and same for the other direction.

---

Given a grid represented as any reasonable format (for example, a matrix of non-negative integers where spaces are `0` is what I predict will be most common), output whether or not the grid can be cleared (refer to the [consensus for output format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19205)).

You may assume there will be no more than 9 colors; this is so that input can be taken as a list of strings of digits.

---

Here are some example test cases. The following are all clearable:

```
. R . G
B . B .
. R . G

[[0, 1, 0, 2], [3, 0, 3, 0], [0, 1, 0, 2]]

. R G .
R . . G
. R G .

[[0, 1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0]]

. R . G
R . G R
. R . .

[[0, 1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]


R G . G
G R . .
. . R G
G . G R

[[1, 2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 2, 1]]
```

The following are not:

```
. R G .
G . . R
G . . R
. R G .

[[0, 1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0]]

R . R . R

[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]

R . .
. . R
. R .

[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]

R G R G
[[1, 2, 1, 2]]

. R B .
R . G R
. G B .
[[0, 1, 3, 0], [1, 0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 3, 0]]
```

---

You may assume that the board contains at least one cell, but either `[[0]]` or `[[1]]` are valid test cases.

---

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest submission (in bytes) for each language is the winner!

Comment: Nice challenge idea.

Comment: Suggested test case: `[[0, 1, 3, 0], [1, 0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 3, 0]] -> False`

Comment: Test cases with more than two colors would be helpful.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Hmm, I'll allow you to assume that the board is non-empty but not that there is a space cell.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES11), 185 bytes

*-3 thanks to l4m2*

Expects a matrix of digits (with 0 for *empty*) and returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
f=m=>m.some(z=(r,y)=>r.some((k,x)=>k?z=0:(h=M=>[-1,0,1,2].map(g=d=>(v=m[Y=y+d%2*++k]?.[X=x+~-d%2*k])<1?g(d):k=M?h[v]?M[Y][X]=0:0:![h[v]|=h[v]+v]))()|h(M=m.map(r=>[...r]))|M<m&&f(M)))!=z
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVJLbsIwEJW67CkgUpHdGCs2mypikl132XUBcr1AhCRSYlKFjwChXqQbFu0hepT2NHWIrQYV6GY0v_fezNhv7_Mynh0OH6tl0n_4-kxAQaDoolQztANUkS2GoGpilJONjvJwB56PMoggEH1GPMIIl1RNXlAKMQRoDUqMYevGd_zedXMZUjGCjfvarxO5xEMWpijGfg5RmIm1DCMxlmIkNavnd0Wd2kNt3bXEGOF9hiJQR4FKS1JKK53fR0PV6yUowhh3Ydcs8H3jTMv5oixmtChT5IinarXMttLBt-18goTwSIeRjrZcko4YHN3a1lGrppUuQLlpbjotUat2GWqbjatzJ6rnoYbWQPlvcwM1wqZmaWuiEybneS4eJ8Xiyk3sYtwuxv5G_6zJ7DyeHeJ8R3v41gmu7M-uP8rg5FFal-WmpqHNV7F__gc)

#### Method

For each empty cell in the input matrix, we call a helper function `h` twice:

- once with no argument to count the colors of the closest non-empty cells in the 4 directions
- once with a new copy `M` of the matrix to remove from `M` the cells whose color appears at least twice; if some deletions occur, it triggers a recursive call to the main function with the updated matrix

#### Commented

```javascript
f = m =>                          // f is a recursive function taking a matrix m[]
m.some(z = (r, y) =>              // for each row r[] at index y in m[]:
  r.some((k, x) =>                //   for each value k at index x in r[]:
    k ?                           //     if k is not zero:
      z = 0                       //       at least 1 non-empty cell -> clear z
    :                             //     else:
      ( h = M =>                  //       h is a helper function taking M
        [-1, 0, 1, 2]             //       we have 4 directions to test
        .map(g = d =>             //       for each direction d:
          ( v = m[                //         load in v the value of the cell at:
              Y = y + d % 2 * ++k //           Y = y + dy * k (where k is pre-
            ]?.[                  //           incremented)
              X = x + ~-d % 2 *k  //           X = x + dx * k
            ]                     //
          ) < 1 ?                 //         if this cell is defined and empty:
            g(d)                  //           move further in the same direction
          :                       //         else:
            k =                   //           reset k to 0 in all cases
            M ?                   //           if M is defined:
              h[v] ?              //             if h[v] is greater than 0:
                M[Y][X] = 0       //               clear M[Y][X]
              :                   //             else:
                0                 //               do nothing
            :                     //           else:
              ![ h[v] |=          //             set h[v] = 0 if h[v] is undefined
                   h[v] + v       //             or h[v] > 0 if h[v] = 0 and v is
              ]                   //             defined
        )                         //       end of map()
      )() |                       //     1st call to h with M undefined
      h(M = m.map(r => [...r])) | //     2nd call to h with M = copy of m[]
      M < m && f(M)               //     do a recursive call if M was modified
  )                               //   end of some()
) != z                            // end of some() / success if z was not cleared
```

Comment: 192 bytes: [`f=m=>m.some(z=(r,y)=>r.some((c,x)=>c?z=0:(h=M=>[1,1,1,1].map(g=(k,d)=>(v=m[Y=y+~-d%2*k]?.[X=x+(d-2)%2*k])<1?g(k+1,d):M?h[v]?M[Y][X]=0:0:h[v]=h[v]+v/v|0))()|h(M=m.map(r=>[...r]))|M<m&&f(M)))!=z`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVFLasMwEN33FO6iYaaWVdvdFJOxT6B9gtCixD9wFBenNYkxvUg3WbT36DW67E0q-QMhLRTBQ2_mvTcM8_a-q9PsdPp4ec69h6_PnDTFmu9rnUFH0LAjUtyMHDbsYNgm6ciPoCRBsQzY8BTXj09QEFQsNRJoScs1Hd1XL70JbyuVcLmigwupF-JQwGWQFFC5gdFHIillqxIh10qulAn3I1sgC2571_Y-ImBfgiA9DGrMZM55oxB7sdSLRQ4CEa-pm_b43tS7fb3N-LYuIAcpfeYEzDEYKubI--Fr0bKzngm8-tsaTuJROQed9az1H284e4Pf7CLpMmgcO6FVjIvOh_sB)

Comment: `h[v]+v/v|0` => `h[v]+v|0` as we don't care what number is added

Comment: @l4m2 Nice catch. We can save another byte with `h[v]|=h[v]+v`.

Answer (score 4):

## Python3, 368 bytes

```py
E=enumerate
def f(b):
 q=[{(x,y):v for x,r in E(b)for y,v in E(r)}]
 for d in q:
  if sum(d.values())==0:return 1
  for i in d:
   if 0==d[i]:
    D={}
    for X,Y in[(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)]:
     j,k=i
     while(c:=(j+X,k+Y))in d:
      if d[c]:D[d[c]]=D.get(d[c],[])+[c];break
      j,k=c
    if(U:={**d,**{I:0 for J in D for I in D[J]if len(D[J])>1}})!=d:q+=[U]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBNc4IwEL3zK9KTCUSH4KVDJz3hQe/O6GRysBIqfqBGsDoMv50mIVS0etl9m31v324O13y1z4bvB1nXIyqyYifkIhdOLBKQwC8UOuBIWQkv@IrCM0j2ElywBGkGRqqryys@N6VEFXcMI9YPRyUFaQJOxQ7Gg/NiW4gTRIhSP5QiL2QGiCJoeqrpsaZrvk9pzFJuShDRsjJA82Z4rpgMEuwjDPtN8jExsU@Q1YA13tC0gT@rdCvgMqRw7c3wxpsj9OfV2MVsycOI6cRpNPgWOdQYM448lT@@pFhsLF0PXjqNEE5DWrpujF23HIe@WXCiD4kMHBvIJlxZbEUGNUSfpKrQG43Do0fZlNcHmWY5TCBjPgYEAxUDjgEbGqijrjo9jpDzKAosreG0Izq9Z6KWZqF6u3N6FNlRVhTcaI3ImtleO/A2otfvuYH/evWgXZ38r14eQlpf/97s1uuu1znv6W3k1fcO776381OB7SlR/Qs)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 109 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υ⁻ι ≔⟦υ⟧υＦυＦＬιＦ⌕Ａ§ικ.«ιＪλκ≔Ｅ⁴ＫＤＬ⁺ι⌊ι✳⊗μθ≔ＥθΦ⁻⪫μω.¬πηＦΦ⁴∧§ημ⊖№η§ημ§≔§θμ⌕§θμ§ημ.≔⪪⪫ＫＡωＬ⌊ιεＦ¬⁼ει⊞υε⎚»⊙υ⬤ι¬⁻λ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVE7b8IwEJ7JrzgxnSWXqRtTBCUClSqCblWHNHGJhWPnYZdWVX97eo4DCCJF9vnO38t5mbW5yVTfn0qpBOBa187ubSv1ARmD1HUlOg5bqV2HksMUpozNo7jr5EHjm3vn4Kj@NC2gYzCsz0IfbImSjfVK6iJWCmO71oX49jBHRlAzgoLfaJISm6XxeTTZuKp@Naj8BJUjzTar8ZFDKsRxKVuRW2n0mSVVQRgplJWrPCthX8eWxn0oUWA1nDd3qA2HlVRWtBgcbozUWHE4jfo4vBiL9XC39HdHQ8MVkhTr4mKr5FB5apG3ohLaEunCOHJGjZuZ4YOg4tw4r00A8ZHdn91iBH1XN/taSRv0@5x83iz4GIO6DUhczHiDT43LVIeCg@9eXn0YWiiRtUi7vyg8VKx/fNMzyJBPyE6NT0rfvO93kMAMkiiBHa2ziH7a@ZpOYRf1D1/qHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as in the diagrams in the question but any character other than `.` and space may be used as a colour. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υ⁻ι ≔⟦υ⟧υＦυ
```

Input the board and start a breadth-first search with that position.

```
ＦＬιＦ⌕Ａ§ικ.«
```

Loop over all of the indices of `.`s in the current position.

```
ιＪλκ
```

Temporarily draw the position to the canvas and jump to the current `.`.

```
≔Ｅ⁴ＫＤＬ⁺ι⌊ι✳⊗μθ
```

Peek in all four orthogonal directions.

```
≔ＥθΦ⁻⪫μω.¬πη
```

Get the first non-`.` character (if any) in each direction.

```
ＦΦ⁴∧§ημ⊖№η§ημ
```

Loop over those characters that appear more than once.

```
§≔§θμ⌕§θμ§ημ.
```

Replace the character with a `.`

```
≔⪪⪫ＫＡωＬ⌊ιε
```

Read the position back from the canvas.

```
Ｆ¬⁼ει⊞υε
```

If this was a new position (i.e. at least two letters were replaced) then add it to the list of positions to search.

```
⎚
```

Clear the canvas ready for the next iteration.

```
»⊙υ⬤ι¬⁻λ.
```

See if any position has no letters left.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just take the input without spaces, so you can replace the `Minus(i, " ")`/`⁻ι ` with `i`/`ι` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sure but this way made it easier to paste in the test cases.

Comment: (Also, in case you missed it, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271912)

Comment: I did miss it indeed, but I'm afraid I'd first have to investigate how to calculate the `atan2` manually in the first place.. Based on the `\u`, I see there are six escape characters and four regular characters among the remaining digits/letters. Seem rather short. 

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 260 bytes

```python
def f(a,w,h):
 if~-any(a):return 1
 for x in range(w*h):
  n=a[:];c=[];[c:=c+[(v,x+i*s)for i,v in enumerate(a[x::s][:t])if v][:1]for s,t in((-w,h),(w,h),(-1,x%w+1),(1,w-x%w))]
  for v,i in c:n[i]*=v not in[u for u,j in c if i-j]
  if n!=a and f(n,w,h):return 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLLbsMgELz7K7aHSuCsJeOkUkXkL0GoQg5uiFoSYfzIpb/uQtwmpOkFDzszyw74dPb7o12/ntw873QLLVE44p7yDEz7VSh7Jopyp33vLLAM2qODCYwFp@y7JmN@kYKtleBy29RCbkXD62YlyIDTyuQdjRaDQzRp239qp7wmSkycd1JwL6lpYQiIyajs0AclIUWcAsmyFgyn53HFAmQ4FgFTKsOx0TCgia0bboWReT2APcYOor@wPR4ubEgDpjhEU0D2qVag7C7EtUvc34Szd71@a1SnO6hBZESUCAwhrBXC@gKW9VaXCJtQpXhVVwldJtsIHtWL4g/4Mafqa@Mq0ZXJMFUiYItzQzOZteqj@y9UlUyXVspkiOpxiBsdiJfwSYjyoUF0r@8jsOulsTheFh/K6y4@G9zuP/5XACdnrCctyaOA0mzZ0ztPku9f0/wN)

Takes input as a 1d array of integers `a` where 0 is an empty cell, and grid dimensions `w,h`. Outputs `1` for true and `None` for false.

The function works by trying every move and for each move that removes any tiles it makes a recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 45 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
œị¹ƙ⁸ḊƇŒṬ€S¬a
ŒṪ_ẠÐḟṠAÞḢ$ƙ$+ç⁸
¬sŒṪȦ?ç@€⁻Ƈ⁸ß€
```

A full program that accepts a list of non-empty<sup>*</sup> lists of non-negative integers where `0` is a space, outputting [via its exit code](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5330/53748) - `1` when possible, `0` otherwise.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5Ie7uw/tPDbzUeOOhzu6jrUfnfRw55pHTWuCD61J5AJxVsU/3LXg8ISHO@Y/3LnA8fC8hzsWqRybqaJ9eDlQC9ehNcVgRSeW2R9e7gDU96hx97F2oMzh@UDO////o6MNdBQMdRSApFGsDpdCtDGYDSLBXBTZWAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##bZLNTsJAFIX39ylumkY0QkLLmh@fwWWZGJQhramtoSXGvwVuSHRjdMVGiAtJTB@glV0bGl9j@iJ1KFMowmYy937nnjkzmTtHT9P@wDo8wnugF7qNFQsluYX1BkoAl9Q0b5EOLCwt3tn8JQzicTL0mf8cjxZvLPCSJ@809DqwLL7P2M80emX@hAXTk@iD@Z9yPJaPoxkfgdBzMtHvVzOatfhcMpzHI06iCS9KyM88aFQBjB5qGspNrGMVCUFXpxYgZtkk4@radhzj3KQSUNOha7Bp9wx4hNVVpDbnmlYto1JGvqqkjFot2y7XZVVgpCBWBV6xfLTAyB5nseW9LedcLEaFWN3glViYC5Yb7Qul5qGU3WonopI7Zwqy7hSPLcTdyqr8f5ba1rMUbqoKRiR8wDbc6IZJsU87Xaz00aWOC12b@/CPhrIoLZqmfw) (uses a zsh wrapper to catch the exit code).

<sup>* Would identify `[[]]` as impossible if given, can be handled for +1 byte by inserting `0` between `¬sŒṪȦ?` and `ç@€⁻Ƈ⁸ß€`.</sup>

##### How?

```
œị¹ƙ⁸ḊƇŒṬ€S¬a - Link 1 (Remove equal colours): ColourCoordinates, Board
œị¹ƙ⁸         - Group the ColourCoordinates by their colours on the Board
     ḊƇ       - keep those groups with length greater than one
       ŒṬ€    - covert each into a 2d array with ones at the given coordinates
          S   - sum them to a single mask
           ¬  - logical NOT (vectorises)
            a - logical AND {Board} (vectorises)
                  -> a copy of Board with identified equal colours set to zero

ŒṪ_ẠÐḟṠAÞḢ$ƙ$+ç⁸ - Link 2 (Try pressing): Board, SpaceCoordinate
ŒṪ               - truthy coordinates {Board} -> all ColourCoordinates
  _              - {those} subtract {SpaceCoordinate} (vectorises) -> Offsets
   ẠÐḟ           - {Offsets} discard if all
                     -> those Offsets for colours in SpaceCoordinate's row or column
            $    - last two links as a monad - f(Offsets):
      Ṡ          -   sign (vectorises) (e.g. [0, -3] -> [0, -1] or [4, 0] -> [1, 0])
           ƙ     -   apply to groups of {Offsets} with equal {Sign}s:
          $      -     last two links as a monad - f(Offsets):
       AÞ        -        sort by absolute value
         Ḣ       -        head -> closest Offset in the direction of {Sign}
             +   - add {SpaceCoordinate} -> back from Offsets to coordinates
              ç⁸ - call Link 1 - f(that, Board)

¬sŒṪȦ?ç@€⁻Ƈ⁸ß€ - Main Link: list of lists of non-negative integers, Board
¬              - logical NOT {Board} (vectorises) -> 1s at spaces, 0s at colours
     ?         - if...
    Ȧ          - ...condition: any and all? -> 1 if all spaces else 0
 s             - ...then: split {that} into chunks of length {Board} (vectorises)
                            -> error! (can't split into chunks of length zero)
  ŒṪ           - ...else: truthy coordinates -> SpaceIndices
      ç@€      - call Link 2 with swapped arguments for each
         ⁻Ƈ⁸   - keep only those which have changed
            ß€ - call this (Main) Link for each
```